# SelectAnnotation deselects also in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, annotations

I tried to select my annotation programmatically. So in my custom map renderer i used this.

```
    _iosMap.SelectAnnotation(myAnnotation, true);
```

myAnnotation got selected all right but right after that it got deselected. (Info window showed for a second than it vanished)I have no idea why. I mean when user tapped in certain regions my program adds annotation to map and right after that it calls SelectAnnotation to display the infowindow.

I tried to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091128/selectannotation-method-of-mapview-calling-deselect-method-also-ios).

```
    void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e) {
     MKMarkerAnnotationView annotationView = (MKMarkerAnnotationView) e.View;
    
     if (someBoolToDetectUnwantedDeselect) {
      _iosMap.SelectAnnotation(annotationView.Annotation, true);
     }
    }
```

But it did not work. I mean annotation got selected(OnDidSelectAnnotationView method fired.) But infowindow didn't appear. How can i solve this?

I tried to use GestureRecognizerShouldBegin(saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835499/preventing-annotation-deselection-in-mkmapview). ) But on select,deselect GestureRecognizerShouldBegin didn't fire.

Addition : I reproduces the issue here.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/s1ahsdum258yqpk/selectannotationproblem.rar/file

When tapped on map anywhere besides pin SelectAnnotation fires in CustomMapRenderer. Infowindow shows for a second than it vanishes.

When i added this to the OnDidDeselectAnnotationView

```
((MKMapView)Control).SelectAnnotation(((MKMapView)Control).Annotations.ElementAt(0), true);
```

In vanishes on the first tap just like before. And on second, third taps it works okay. Why first?

Comment: Can you please share more code in your custom renderer to reproduce this problem? I test the official sample and `SelectAnnotation` works well on my side.

Comment: I added a link. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding delay.

```
private void OnTap(UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
   //
    PerformSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("ShowAnnotation"), null, 0.6f);
}

[Export("ShowAnnotation")]
void ShowAnnotation()
{
    ((MKMapView)Control).SelectAnnotation(((MKMapView)Control).Annotations.ElementAt(0), true);
}
```

Comment: You can mark it as an answer which will help more people with same problem!